# Searching for a better workflow to get a cropped PDF and EPS graphics - Stage 1

Tags: dvips, pdfcrop, pdftops, epstopdf, epstool

I am using TeX Live 2010. I don't use MikTeX anymore because of many troubles I found in the past.

### Input files:

*gridon.tex:*

```
% gridon.tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](3,3)
\pscircle(1.5,1.5){1}
\rput[tr](3,3){3}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

*gridoff.tex:*

```
% gridoff.tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](3,3)
\pscircle(1.5,1.5){1}
\rput[tr](3,3){3}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

*main.tex:*

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[hiresbb]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=2]{gridon}
\vspace{5mm}

\includegraphics[scale=2]{gridoff}
\end{document}
```

### Methods:

*MethodA.bat:*

```
echo off
latex %1
dvips %1
ps2pdf %1.ps
pdfcrop --hires %1
pdftops -eps %1-crop.pdf
```

*MethodB.bat:*

```
echo off
latex %1
dvips %1 -E -o %1.eps
epstool --copy --bbox %1.eps %1-crop.eps
epstopdf --hires %1-crop.eps
```

### Results:

[image]

Comment: You need to use `<pre> .. </pre>` HTML tags for non-TeX code, otherwise the `%` will be taken as comment.

Comment: @Martin: Or even better use [one of the language tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971) (though there doesn't seem to be highlighting for .bat files)

Comment: If I may give you some tips about this question: You might want to add a short introduction (as always) and also state that you (mainly?) looking for a MS Windows solution. Also, all the `del` lines in your batch files are not required to see the cropping process but make the code blocks hard to read. I would recommend to remove them.

Comment: Did you tried the `preview` package or the `standalone` class already? Would you like an answer based on them? They produce the DVI or PDF already cropped. However an EPS from DVI will most likely not have the correct HiResBoundingBox.

Comment: Another idea: measure the size of the content in TeX and print it converted to `bp` in an external file. These values can then be used to build a HiResBoundingBox header for the (E)PS produced by `dvips`. This would save you a few conversion steps.

Comment: @Martin: Method B has fewer steps than method A, but the size of EPS in method B is bigger than one produced by method A. So I prefer to find a way to reduce the size of EPS produced by method B now. Later I will  taste standalone and preview  packages.

Comment: By the way, why do you care if the EPS files are smaller? Are you planning to distribute them alone? Usually we are only using them to feed to latex, dvips and then ps2pdf to produce a final document that includes these EPS files as figures. In this case, the size of the EPS files themselves is irrelevant and the only important thing is the size of the whole document PDF, which may be smaller or larger depending on the details of the situation (see: [this whitepaper](http://pdfsizeopt.googlecode.com/files/pts_pdfsizeopt2009.psom.pdf)).

Comment: I want to put my PSTricks codes and their corresponding PDF or EPS on a hosting service. Bandwidth and storage spaces are important points to be considered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend method A, because the EPS files will in general be much smaller.

You noticed "bad" cropping with method A. The reason for this is subtle: your use of pstricks produces a PDF where the font used for labelling the grid (eg, the figure "3") is Helvetica and it is *not* embedded in the PDF. Therefore ghostscript and adobe reader have to use a subsitute font. Most viewers (including the many viewers based on ghostscript, also xpdf) will use a version of Helvetica. Adobe's viewer will substitute ArialMT (on windows at least), which is a slightly different shape and therefore gets cut off. You can check this with Adobe reader on the "fonts" tab of the "document properties" dialog. You can solve this problem by producing a file with the fonts embedded. One way to do this is to change your method A to use `ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress %1.ps %1.pdf`.

Why does method B seem to be superior? Actually I was quite confused for a while because on Ubuntu the two methods do produce the same bounding box. Which is to be expected, since pdfcrop and epstool both use `gs -sDEVICE=bbox` to generate it. So why do you see a difference? Well, I found that the miktex version of epstopdf has a bug in it: it rounds the bounding box to an integer number of points. *In this particular case* this had the effect of cancelling the clipping, but in general it could make the clipping worse. I'll file a bug against miktex tomorrow, but in the meantime this is another reason to prefer method A if you are using miktex. (The miktex version of epstopdf is a reimplementation in C of the bugless original perl script).

Comment: That comment from Alann Munn is in relation to fonts that are explicitly included by tex. Here, the use of the font is "hidden" from tex by the pstricks specials.

Comment: @xport: you can add a font with `dvips -h hv______.pfb <file>.dvi` for Helvetica. The fonts are available with the AdobeReader. However, it makes no real sense to emded the standard PostScript fonts because they are already present on any PostScript printer. If you want to embed all PS fonts then create a driver file `config.myps` and add lines like `h hv______.pfb` for the fonts and then use `dvips -P config.myps ...`

Comment: the `-dPDFSETTINGS` is a ghostscript switch and has nothing to do with the `dvips` run.

Comment: Yes, it's usually a good idea to use prepress settings. You can read what that does [here](http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/tags/ghostscript-9.02/doc/Ps2pdf.htm#Options).

Comment: @xport: the underscores are part of the file name, that's all. You have to use your file name of the helvetica font.

Comment: @xport: again: the font is _not_ part of any TeX distribution you have to get it from elsewhere, eg from an old installation of the Adobe Reader

Comment: @xport: `dvips` needs the font and it searches in the already existing font directories, eg `$TEXMF/fonts/type1/adobe/base13/` would be a good choice for the basic PostScript fonts

Comment: Herbert's solution actually works, it starts embedding the fonts to the resulting PS file. But we need to specify the font file name explicitly. Lev's solution is more elegant but it starts embedding the font to the PDF file. I choose Lev's solution for the sake of simplicity. :-)

Comment: @Lev: I noticed that T3Font_3 cannot be embedded to PDF even though I use `ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress %1.ps %1.pdf`. Please see this issue in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22621/how-to-speed-up-rendering-a-pstricks-object-with-a-custom-fill/22633#22633