# What is the file name of Helvetica font used by PSTricks grid labels?

Tags: fonts, pstricks

This is related to Herbert's comment in answer for [Which one is recommended to get cropped PDF and EPS graphics?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22120/which-one-is-recommended-to-get-cropped-pdf-and-eps-graphics/22501#22501).

He said I can use `dvips -h hv______.pfb input.dvi` to embed font to the resulting PS file. But I don't know which font file corresponds to the font used by PSTricks grid labels.

I have a list of font files with names begin with `h` as follows, but I don't know which one I must use. :-)

[image]

Question: What is the file name of Helvetica font used by PSTricks grid labels?

Note: I am using Windows 7 with TeX Live 2010 installed and my workflow is `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`. You may need this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Helvetica font is just one of the 35 predefined fonts. You can probably get through by saying

```
\psset[pstricks]{gridfont=NimbusSanL-Regu}
```

in your file and then run `dvips` with the option

```
-h uhvr8a.pfb
```

that will load the URW clone of Helvetica which is provided in TeX Live.

Answer (score 1):

`\psset{gridfont=helvetica}` should work without the additional header using for dvips.
I have these fonts in my example pdf:

```
voss@shania:~/Documents> pdffonts latex6.pdf
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
SVYBYQ+helvetica                     Type 1C           yes yes no       8  0
AQAEUC+CMR10                         Type 1C           yes yes no      11  0
```

Comment: That's kind of magic, isn't it?

Comment: In my machine, it does not work.

Comment: then it is a "problem" :-) with my configuration. However, the URW fonts should be embedded by default with a standard TeXLive installation

Comment: The combination of `\psset[pstricks]{gridfont=...}` and `ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress %1.ps` is the best solution to embed font to the PDF. No need to explicity use header switch as in `dvips -h hv______.pfb input.dvi`.