# How to speed up rendering a PSTricks object with a custom fill

Tags: pstricks

Because PSTricks does not provide us with dotted and x-like fill styles, I must create my own custom fill style using `pst-fill` package.

However, the rendering is too slow and sometimes out of memory.

[image]

```
\documentclass[cmyk]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-fill}

\psboxfill{%
\psset{unit=1pt}
\begin{pspicture}(3.6,3.6)
\psdot(1.8,1.8)
\end{pspicture}%
}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-2)(2,2)
\pscircle[
    fillstyle=solid,
    opacity=0.25,
    fillcolor=gray,
    fillsep=0.4,
    addfillstyle=boxfill]
    (0,0){2}
\pscircle[
    linecolor=red,
    linestyle=dashed,
    linewidth=2pt]
    (0,0){1}
\end{pspicture}
\caption{The magnetic field $\vec{B}$ is directed perpendicularly out of the page.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How to speed up rendering a PSTricks object with a custom fill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\psboxfill{%
  \psset{unit=1pt}
  \begin{pspicture}(3.6,3.6)
  \qdisk(1.8,1.8){1.8}
  \end{pspicture}%
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the reason why using `\psdot` runs slowly. When I highlighted the PDF output, there are unnecessary hidden objects as follows. It might be a feature of `\psdot`.

[image]

---

Thus, to speed up, use `\pscircle*` instead of `\psdot` as follows, and the hidden objects disappear.

```
\documentclass[cmyk]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-fill}

\psboxfill{%
\psset{unit=1pt}
\begin{pspicture}(3.6,3.6)
%\psdot(1.8,1.8)
\pscircle*(1.8,1.8){1.8}
\end{pspicture}%
}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-2)(2,2)
\pscircle[
    fillstyle=solid,
    opacity=0.25,
    fillcolor=gray,
    fillsep=0.4,
    addfillstyle=boxfill]
    (0,0){2}
\pscircle[
    linecolor=red,
    linestyle=dashed,
    linewidth=2pt]
    (0,0){1}
\end{pspicture}
\caption{The magnetic field $\vec{B}$ is directed perpendicularly out of the page.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

Another drawback when using `\psdot` is: `\psdot` uses `T3Font_0` as follows

[image]

This font cannot be embedded to the PDF output, even though you use `ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress input.ps`.

Comment: This font is actually embedded in this case. Adobe reader has a strange way of dealing with type 3 fonts.

Comment: @Lev: I think the font is not embedded since `pdfcrop` also cannot produce correct BB.

Comment: The font is embedded. I did check before writing. You can check yourself with multivalent, pdffonts or acrobat professional preflight tool (and probably many other tools). Also, `pdfcrop` produces the correct bbox for me.